# paste = mashed potatoes?

Tags: synonyms, vocabulary

Is **paste** a correct term to refer to **mashed potatoes**?

I heard it today from a non-native speaker from **India** and I was a bit surprised.

Comment: Why the hell did somebody downgrade my question? What's wrong with it?

Comment: It's _downvote_, not _downgrade_, and if you hover over the downvote button, the ToolTip reads, "This question doesn't show any research effort." Did you look up _paste_ in a dictionary? Did you Google "paste means potatoes" or some other query? Instead, all I see is, "I heard it today and I was surprised." I'm surprised you're surprised by a downvote.

Comment: Yes. I looked it up on a few sources and couldn't figure out on my own if the guy was right or not. Hence my question. Sorry for asking, I may say.

Comment: People love to downvote on this site. Don't let it faze you. @J.R. the question will not be adequately answered by consulting a dictionary; a good answer will explain *why* **paste** may or may not be appropriate in this collocation.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking, but I think you'll find this community more accepting of your question when you phrase it in a way that clearly indicates that you've done some research. If you don't tell us where you've looked, how do we know? And what prevents us from the same fruitless searches? Pretend you didn't write this question, and read it at face value: doesn't it seem like something you'd ask Siri?

Comment: @jlovegren:  Compare this to what someone wrote asking about the [difference between _desire_ and _motivation_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120295). That question is equally basic, but the way it's asked is completely different. Nobody's downvoted _that_ question; it's garnered three upvotes in a mere 30 minutes. I never said this question could be easily answered with a dictionary, I only said that, given how little research was evidenced, I'm not shocked by a downvote, and I don't think the fault lies with a downvote-happy population.

Comment: For God's sake, are you serious, J.R.? I won't ever write an essay in order to know such a stupid thing as the one I'm asking in this question. I simply thought that on this board, if somebody knows the answer, they reply. If they don't, probably because they are not native speakers, they can just let go. But don't worry, next time I don't have something so sophisticated to ask as to write 20 lines for it, I will ask elsewhere ;)

Comment: There is no need to use the word *paste*. A quicker and common way to refer to mashed potatoes is the word *mash*.

Comment: 20 lines? Who said anything about 20 lines? You asked "why the hell did somebody downgrade," and I offered a theory. All I said was, "There's no research." Maybe something as simple as, "I Googled `slang for mashed potatoes`, and I looked up `paste` in the Urban Dictionary, but I couldn't find anything. Still, I wanted to ask here..." would have warded off the downvotes. But why ask "What's wrong with the question" if you're going to complain about the answer? Sheesh.

Comment: @Ricky: That makes two of us. The next time someone bellyaches about their downvote, and asks for an explanation, I don't think I'll bother, either. Ciao. :^)

Comment: In any case, just to answer one last time J.R., just like there was no need for me to write all that - we're not on `stackoverflow` - there is no need for anybody to waste their time reading 6 more lines when the question is so simple and can be summarized in a few words. But whatever, now I know what the spirit is here. ;)

Comment: Well, at least I learned a new word today: `to bellyache` :D   ciao ;)

Comment: My guess is that, in some language, the word for "paste" could be used for mashed potatoes, and that person didn't realize that it could not be used for this in English.

Comment: You should have mentioned in the question that "non-native speaker" was Indian.  They have [distinct dialects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_English) of English, and it might well be true in their own dialect.  Modifying the question to indicate the origin might help you get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @Ricky I understand your consternation, but please understand ours, which is that this site is supposed to be about academic-level questions of English and its nuance. Every day we fight the flood of drive-by question-askers who treat the site like it is some kind of novelty forum and then shout abuse at us when we point them to the rules. If your question is so simple, it is not on-topic. If it is not so simple, you have to demonstrate why. If you don't want to do the research yourself first, try Yahoo Answers.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this website again and remembered about this fruitless discussion from last year. I must say I had a good laugh when reading this last comment by @KitFox, which received even 9 upvotes! :D   
If I go on http://english.stackexchange.com/about, I see that I can "Ask about... Word choice and usage" and "Dialect differences", which describes ****exactly**** my question. I wonder what FumbleFingers, tchrist, TrevorD, Robusto and John Lawler were thinking when they decided to close my question because "primarily opinion-based" (!!!!).

Answer (score 3):

Mashed potatoes may end up with a paste-like consistency if made poorly but no, I don't believe anyone has ever referred to the dish itself as "paste."  Non-native speakers are probably not a great resource, but I can understand the usage.  There is a spreadable nature to some pleasantly creamy mashed potatoes and some spreadable foodstuffs are marketed as "paste" - "shrimp paste" and "chili paste" spring readily to mind.

Comment: Oh ok. The thing is, the guy was Indian and was quite convinced about that term (I had to ask him to repeat a few times, as I had no clue what he was referring to!). I still have to understand to which extent an Indian person speaks correct English, but that doesn't have much to do with this question :)

Comment: We used to call my mother's mashed potatoes "wallpaper paste." Not to her face, of course.

Comment: @KitFox: I think "paste" is a common metaphor for bad mashed potatoes. When I Googled `"mashed potatoes like paste"` I got several hundred results. I don't think _paste_ is a synonym for mashed potatoes per se, but some might consider it slang for _bad_ mashed potatoes. Somehow, it's not too hard for me to imagine a soldier in a mess tent saying "Meat loaf and paste for lunch again!"

Comment: Ricky, that's probably just a feature of Indian English and that Indian chap just assumed that it's used in other forms of English, even though it's not.

Comment: Wallpaper paste used to commonly be made from potatoes. Still is sometimes: https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=0fn&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&q=wallpaper+paste+potato+flour&sa=X&ei=gErwUbXkHIe69gTFp4CoDA&ved=0CCoQ7xYoAA&biw=1345&bih=833 It's a very short hop from spreading potato paste on the back of your wallpaper to telling your maw how much you enjoyed the paste and gravy she made for dinner.

Comment: The funny thing was that I ate mashed potatoes at the same canteen a few minutes later and they didn't resemble paste at all. :D

Answer (score 2):

> Is **paste** a correct term to refer to **mashed potatoes**?

No. There is no need to use the word *paste*. A quicker and common way to refer to mashed potatoes is the word *mash* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/mash_2

Comment: I won't dispute that, however, the fact that another word may be more common doesn't preclude a different word from being used. The O.P. didn't ask for the most _common_ term.

Answer (score 2):

It might be your friend was thinking of

[**creamed potatoes**](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/emeril-lagasse/creamed-potatoes-recipe/index.html) (in the US) otherwise known as [**purea**](http://www.gustissimo.it/ricette/contorni-patate/purea-di-patate.htm) in Italy or maybe the French creamy potato dish [**Aligot**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aligot). Now that's what I call "paste-like"!

[image: Aligot]

Comment: Southern Italy or southern England?

Comment: I erroneously thought it was *southern US* style of mashed potatoes. But their preferred way of mashing is thick, almost dry-like. The complete opposite. Purea in Italy is nearly always creamed regardless of region.

Comment: I'm still not sure who you are referring to when you say 'they', Italians or Americans. But in the US south, there are 'mashed potatoes' which are very lumpy, and 'creamed potatoes' which can be almost poured. As to the OP's word, 'paste' is not used as a label for the dish in US English as far as I am aware.

Comment: My hypothesis is that the OP's Indian friend saw this dish and described it as being a "paste". In Indian cuisine, many of their curry/spicy sauces or blends are sold in paste form in glass jars. Just my hypothesis.